# Нули - в конец. Дан одномерный массив

Tags: c++

1 курс универа. C++. Основы программирования.

Нули - в конец. Дан одномерный массив. Все его элементы, не  равные  нулю, переписать (сохраняя их порядок) в  начало  массива,  а  нулевые элементы - в конец массива. Все действия производить в имеющемся массиве.

Comment: Здесь за вас никто делать не будет. Обратитесь к одногруппникам или фрилансерам за денежку. Или же покажите, что уже сделано и что в вашем коде не работает.

Answer (score 1):

В С++ это делается двумя функциями:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int a[] = {0,1,2,0,3,0};

    // Удаляем нули между элементами, а потом заполняем конец нулями.
    std::fill(std::remove(std::begin(a), std::end(a), 0), std::end(a), 0);

    for (auto x : a) std::cout << x << ',';
}
```

Comment: Зачем? Он же ничему не научится. Тупо перепишет и сдаст. Правда, есть надежда, что не поймёт или преподу объяснить не сможет... ;-)

Comment: Да, давайте сложные примеры, что бы препод сразу понял, что его студент такого написать не мог

Comment: @kff Он не сдаст, так как от него требуется самому реализовать эти функции.  Так что для него от этого сообщения пользы никакой. Более того правильно было бы использовать std::stable_partition,.

Comment: У нас просто пока еще даже лекций не было. Код, что называется высший пилотаж.. А мне попроще бы